# .Net MVC 5 querying models that have a many-to-many-relationship with ApplicationUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-relationship

I have the classes `Student` and `Class`.

```
public class Student : ApplicationUser
{
    public DateTime DateBorn     { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Class> Classes { get; set; }
}

public class Class
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }
    public string ProfessorId { get; set; }
    public Professor Professor { get; set; }
    public short Size { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public Term Term { get; set; }
    public bool Enrollable { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to get the `Classes` at which a `Student` is enrolled. I thought of using the method `class.Students.Contains()` inside of the method `.Where()`, but it returns me an exception.

```
// GET: Classes/Calendar
public async Task<ActionResult> Calendar(int? year, Term? term)
{
    year = year ?? DateTime.Now.Year;
    term = term ?? (Term)(DateTime.Now.Month / 4);

    var student = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());

    var classes = db.Classes
                .Where(c => c.Students.Contains(student) && c.Year == year && c.Term == term);

    return View(await classes.ToListAsync());
}
```

The exception: `Unable to create a constant value of type 'Demosthenes.Core.Models.Student'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.`

How can I do this properly without having to write an explicit join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If primary key property of `Student` is `Id` and `User.Identity.GetUserId()` return type is the same with `Student::Id`, you can try this.

```
var id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var classes = db.Classes
   .Where(c => c.Students.Any(s => s.Id == id) 
               && c.Year == year && c.Term == term);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a step back and change your table structure.

For a many-to-many relationship, you need to add a junction table in the middle, e.g.

```
Student
StudentClass
Class
```

You code will then become

```
var classes = db.Classes
            .Where(c => c.StudentClasses
                         .Any(x=>x.StudentId == student.Id) 
                     && c.Year == year && c.Term == term);
```